# How does knex handle default values in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, knex.js

We currently use mysql / knex, and I'm adding SQLite as a database for testing purposes. I'm getting

> Knex:warning - sqlite does not support inserting default values. Set the `useNullAsDefault` flag to hide this warning. (see docs http://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert).

How does Knex handle default values? Does it just drop any defaults, or does it add in the defaults after an insert as following `UPDATE` statements?

I don't want to change all of our codebase (swap out all default values), trying to do the minimal change that will allow me to run SQLite in our tests... concerned this will introduce bugs.

Answer (score 23):

I'm learning `knex.js` so I can use it in a project involving PostgreSQL. While trying out Sqlite I came across this issue.

Turns out it's [documented!](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert)

> If one prefers that undefined keys are replaced with `NULL` instead of `DEFAULT` one may give `useNullAsDefault` configuration parameter in knex config.

And they give this code:

```js
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
     filename: "./mydb.sqlite"
  },
  useNullAsDefault: true
});

knex('coords').insert([{x: 20}, {y: 30}, {x: 10, y: 20}])
// insert into `coords` (`x`, `y`) values (20, NULL), (NULL, 30), (10, 20)"
```

This removed the warning message for me.

Comment: Please note that the `sqlite` client expects only a `filename` property instead of `host`/`user`/`password`/`database` as shown in your code snippet.

Comment: Thank you @cyanbeam I don't know how I missed that. 

Thanks!